# Auto update data onFocus without refresh

Tags: javascript, onfocus

I have a webpage for that allows the user to add attachments (stored in a directory)
For this I use a greybox to popup a window and there the user can view add or delete 
docs as they see fit, this all works fine.

The problem I have is that when the user closes the popup the total of attachments which
is displayed on the main page isn't updated and requires a refresh, which I want to avoid.
I would like to have this data automatically update preferably when the focus changes back 
to the main page. I'm on Solaris so I can get the total of files easily its just the display update I need.

All help appreciated

Frankie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In such situations I prefer to handle onPopupClose instead of onFocusChange. After a little search, apparently greybox let you do that by defining a callback function (described [here](http://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/237532-refresh-div-on-parent-page-on-close-of-greybox/)):

```
GB_show(caption, url, /*optional*/ height, width, callback_fn)
```

So you may write something like this:

```
GB_show('Popup', 'popup_url', 500, 500, function() {
    updateTotalAttachmentCount();
});
```